# How to prove that $ \chi(G)\alpha(G)\ge |G|? $

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Given a graph $G=(V, E)$, denote by $\chi(G)$ the chromatic number (i.e., the smallest number of colors so that each pair of adjacent vertices with different colors) and denote by $\alpha(G)$ the independent number set of $G$.

How to prove that

$$
\chi(G)\alpha(G)\ge |G|?
$$

I am not very sure about the definition of $\alpha(G)$. For example, if $G$ is a 3-partite graph on vertices 9, and there are only 3 independent sets and each part with 3 vertices.  In this case, $\alpha(G)=3$.

Comment: According to the definition I'm familiar with the independence number $\alpha(G)$ is defined as the cardinality of an independent set with the maximum number of vertices. So if $G$ is a *complete* $3$-partite graph on $9$ vertices with $3$ vertices in each part (i.e $G=K_{3,3,3}$) then yes, $\alpha(G)=3$. But in general, knowing that $G$ is a $3$-partite graph on $9$ vertices is not enough to deduce that $\alpha(G)=3$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Thanks. But how to prove this inequality?

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=|G|$. Consider a coloring of $G$ with $\chi(G)$ colors. Then by the pigeonhole principle, there is a color that is used at least $\frac{n}{\chi(G)}$ times. Now all of the vertices of that color form an independent set (by the definition of coloring) so $\alpha(G)\geq \frac{n}{\chi(G)}$ which is what you want to prove.